# Famous neural networks for regression

Tags: keras, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I have come across many neural network architecture for classification problems. AlexNet, ResNet, VGGNet, GoogLeNet etc... Is there similar networks for regression problems which can be used for transfer learning?

Answer (score 6):

Alright, all those architecture are not only for **classification**, the only shift you have to make for modifying a DL model from classification to regression is to change the top layer. For example in the VGGNET the last layer could be :

```py
Dense(25, activation='softmax')
```

That means that we want to predict 25 outputs with a probability distribution (classification)

But it could be

```py
Dense(1, activation='linear')
```

With the exact same architecture, it will output a number (regression)

So in the case of transfer learning you can just take an existing architecture that is pretrained on classification tasks, remove the top layer and do whatever you want.

Comment: So for a multivariable regression with 'n' outputs, I can make the last layer something like this

    Dense(n, activation='linear')

Comment: Exactly, and use a mean_squared_error as loss. Also, I'm saying linear activation but you can also use sigmoid or leaky relu, you will then need to normalize your target so that it can be between [0, 1] (in order to be compared with the output of your model). And then denormalizing it during inference